# OrientDB shortestPath() using specific edge @class?

Tags: java, orientdb

The `shortestPath()` function takes a direction as it's 3rd argument. How can I modify the function so that instead it only traverses edges of a specific class? I believe I can just add the class as a second argument on line 106:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/b21429d600f87193611eed3d33b90d5fb9c2f61e/graphdb/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/graph/sql/functions/OSQLFunctionShortestPath.java

If I do that however, do I need to rebuild from source? How can I just create a custom function to use in my queries?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html)? Scroll down to __Custom functions in Java__.

Comment: I saw that and it is useful if you are using the javaAPI, but I want to be able to call my custom function from within an SQL query, which requires me to build my own plugin and register it in the orientdb-server-config.xml file. This is more involved and isn't really covered well in the documentation.

Comment: In the end of the page has an example that calls the custom function defined from with an SQL Query.

Comment: Yes but the documentation does not really explain the process of building a plugin.jar file, copying it to the /plugins directory, etc. That's what I was getting at.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I was able to create a plugin and install it in OrientDB. I'll probably do a tutorial about that.
And the function you're talking will be out in the next release. See [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/1975#event-289349880).

Comment: This is great, when will 2.0.9 be released?

Comment: The release cycles are very short, like two weeks. __2.0.8__ was released two days ago.

Comment: About [that tutorial](https://gist.github.com/vitorenesduarte/57624340568cebfa7f34).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just implemented in OrientDB v.2.0.9 and 2.1. 
Both will be released in next days, if you want to try it now you can compile from source (branches "2.0.x" and "develop")

current signature of the function is this:

`shortestPath(<sourceVertex>, <destinationVertex>, [<direction>, [ <edgeTypeAsString> ]])`

example usage

`SELECT shortestPath(#12:0, #12:10, null, "MyEdgeClass")`